# Apache Solr search optimization issue

Tags: solr

I am working under the search team an e-commerce startup. I am recently faced with an issue in locality search where a user writes "Sector 29 Gurgaon" and we provide arbitrary places in Gurgaon that have a prefix match and showing the actual Sector 29 below in the results as it is not a prefix match because the locality name stored in our database is "Sector 29". We are using Apache Solr to store our data.

I tried sorting the results by Distance or relevance score provided by Solr, but it did not seem to work

Comment: Can you please provide more details as to what the data is and what are you expecting back from SOLR?